# How can I break up long tasks in React app

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I'm trying to optimize an Reactjs app using the performance tool of Google Chrome.
Here you can see a screenshot of one long task:
[image]

From here I got lost; from what I can see, this long task manages to render some of my react components (the pinky bars), but sincerely I don't understand why it is trying to render them all in the same task.

If I achieve to undestand this, maybe I can find a solution to break those tasks in smaller parts.
Here is a tree representation of the components rendered in this task:

```
Layout
---- Navbar, Sidebar, Routes
Footer
```

Layout and Footer stands at the same level, all the other compnent are child of Layout